# Win32_DiskDrive and eSATA

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, wmi, drive

I am trying to detect removable drives using WMI and currently I am filtering by `InterfaceType` to include only drives with a USB interface. I was wondering if there is a way to detect eSATA drives or in other words what is the interface type given to eSATA drives by the `Win32_DiskDrive` class.

Currently I don't have an eSATA drive at hand and so I'm not sure what the interface type is supposed to be as eSATA or SATA is not listed as a valid value for the `InterfaceType` member [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Currently the values listed are:

```
SCSI
HDC
IDE
USB
1394
```

So I was wondering if someone can help me here?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it will come under 'USB' or can use the code below to find the one :

```
Dim Mq As New Management.ObjectQuery("WQL", "Select Caption,DeviceID,InterfaceType from Win32_DiskDrive ") ' you can include where InterfaceType='USB'
Dim scop As New ManagementScope("root\cimv2")
Dim MobSrchr As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scop, Mq)
Dim Disks As New List(Of String)

For Each mob As ManagementObject In MobSrchr.Get
    Dim DrivInfo As String = Nothing
    DrivInfo = "Caption : " + mob.Properties("Caption").Value + Environment.NewLine
    DrivInfo += "Device ID : " + mob.Properties("DeviceID").Value + Environment.NewLine
    DrivInfo += "InterfaceType : " + mob.Properties("InterfaceType").Value + Environment.NewLine
    Disks.Add(DrivInfo)
Next
```